# Python: Optimizing data frame processing

Tags: python, pandas, parallel-processing

I have processed raw data in multiple pandas data frames. Each data frame contains **individual user data and which social network they have clicked in time series**. Each data frame roughly represent a year or two together and I want to get everything into one after processing.

Inside the loop each data frame I first convert to following structure to get aggregated data.

```
    year  month  social_clicks, Gender
0   2010    01  google, yahoo, google, google, facebook, facebook, m,f,m
1   2010    02  facebook, yahoo, google, google, facebook, facebook, m,f,m
2   2010    03  yahoo, yahoo, google, google, facebook, facebook, f,f,m
3   2010    04  google, yahoo, google, twitter, facebook, facebook, f,f,f
4   2010    05  facebook, yahoo, google, google, facebook, facebook, m,f,m
5   2010    06  twitter, yahoo, google, twitter, facebook, google, m,f,f
```

Eventually the Goal is to process above time series data into following data frame structure.

```
    year  month  google  yahoo  facebook  twitter M F
0   2010    01    3       1         2       0     2 1
1   2010    02    2       1         3       0     2 1
2   2010    03    2       2         2       0     1 2
```

I iterate over list that contains all the individual data frames while converting them into above aggregated structures. I want to parallelize this process to speed up the processing.

```
pre_processed_dfs = []
finalized_dfs = []
        for frame in pre_processed_dfs:

            ## Calculate the gender per month
            gender_df = frame.groupby(['year','month'])['Gender'].apply(
                lambda x: ','.join(x)).reset_index()

            df_gender = gender_df.Gender.str.split(',', expand=True)
            df_gender = pd.get_dummies(df_gender, prefix='', prefix_sep='')
            df_gender = df_gender.groupby(df_gender.columns, axis=1).sum()
            df_gender_agg = pd.concat([gender_df, df_gender], axis=1)
            df_gender_agg.drop('Gender', axis=1, inplace=True)

            ## construct data frame to maintain monthly social clicks
            social_df = frame.groupby(['year','month'])['social_clicks'].apply(
                lambda x: ','.join(x)).reset_index()

            df = social_df.social_clicks.str.split(',', expand=True)
            df = pd.get_dummies(df, prefix='', prefix_sep='')
            df = df.groupby(df.columns, axis=1).sum()
            social_df_agg = pd.concat([social_df, df], axis=1)
            social_df_agg.drop('social_clicks', axis=1, inplace=True)

            social_df_agg.set_index(['year', 'month'], inplace=True)
            df_gender_agg.set_index(['year', 'month'], inplace=True)

            social_gender_df = pd.merge(social_df_agg, df_gender_agg, left_index=True, right_index=True)

            social_gender_df.reset_index(level=social_gender_df.index.names, inplace=True)
            finalized_dfs.append(social_gender_df)
final_df = pd.concat(finalized_dfs)
```

When I run with smaller data sets above process completes fast. But when I switch to run with actual data sets process runs really really long hours. I believe most time consuming part is the section where i split and join and also doing merge.

Can I parallelize this process where i hand over processing of each data frame in that list to a thread. In addition to that can I speed up the joins and merges that are in this loop.

I was looking at CPU & Memory usage:

```
PID    COMMAND      %CPU  TIME     #TH    #WQ  #PORT MEM    PURG   CMPRS  PGRP  PPID  STATE    BOOSTS         %CPU_ME %CPU_OTHRS UID
4565   python2.7    99.9  14:56:32 9/1
```

I also had put to print statement one at the top of for loop and other just after reseting the index it has not reached the reseting line of code.

Answer (score 1):

This should be

```
df.set_index(['year', 'month']) \
  .iloc[:, 0].str.split(r',\s*').apply(pd.value_counts).fillna(0).reset_index()
```

[image]

Comment: sorry made a mistake in writing the question. editing now

Comment: I initially start with individual records each record is representing what they click and gender with year month

Answer (score 0):

You can use `crosstab`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

size = 100
sites = "google,yahoo,facebook,twitter".split(",")
year = np.random.choice([2015, 2016], size)
month = np.random.choice(np.arange(1, 13), size)
gender = np.random.choice(["m", "f"], size)
click = np.random.choice(sites, size)

df = pd.DataFrame({"year":year, "month":month, "gender":gender, "click":click})

gender_counts = pd.crosstab([df.year, df.month], [df.gender])
click_counts = pd.crosstab([df.year, df.month], [df.click])
```